# Karate - Robot for Java Based Desktop application. Unable to identify controls using Inspect.exe

Tags: karate, inspect.exe

I have implemented Karate for Functional Regression API Tests and Karate-Gatling for Performance tests and its working exceptionally well within our project. Now we wanted to expand Karate to UI Automation as well and in that regard we started with one Desktop application built using Java. We are trying to use inspect.exe to recognize the controls within the application, but Inspect.exe will only identify the whole window but none of the controls inside it. I tried few other inspect tools but none seems to identify any fields within the application. Is there any other tools using which i can inspect the controls ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: closing as duplicate - that said, if you are willing to contribute, I personally think karate can easily be enhanced to detect swing controls as it is written in java. but please note that this is not a priority of the project leads right now